# In Wall Panel for Security System and Camera Cabling

Tags: electrical, conduit, security, ethernet

I'm in the process of overhauling my home network and installing some door and motion sensors. I'd like to drop everything down into the Master bedroom, where I will install a panel that is set in the stud space. I see that most of these panels have knockouts in them for running conduit. If I used conduit coming out of the top of the box, would it extend all the way into the attic space? i.e. if you are in the attic you will see a little conduit poking up through the top plate of the wall.

Even though it is just low voltage POE Cat6 and security cabling I want everything to be up to NEC standards.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify a specific question? Right now, it's a bit ambiguous and a thorough review of NEC wiring methods for low voltage systems is beyond the scope of this site. Do you *want* to use conduit (ex. to make it easier to pull future cables)?

Comment: Even if conduit isn't required, I'd definitely recommend it to make future changes easier. When I redid the bathroom that's roughly in the middle of our house, I took the opportunity to put 3 1" conduits in the wall from basement to attic. Had no use for them then, but when I later needed to run wire it was much easier than fishing it through a hole

Comment: I do not think it is a beyond the scope of this site. Conduit to the panel is fine,And could see it if your always upgrading .Or it only has to be in to protect cables.Both work .And nothing wrong with doing a better job.

Comment: yes, thje conduit should go "all the way"

Comment: I answered a similar question yesterday regarding how to do this with the attic. You can find the answer [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/171599/96729).